# Different types of web service options

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, asmx

What are my options when it comes to web services?. I've bee working so far with .asmx and windows communication foundation or wcf. Any other approaches out there worth considering? Thanks.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology that should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 1):

[Asp.net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is an other option, and is best suited if your client is web application as it is Rest base and calling it from ajax is rather easy.

Comment: I was checking WebAPI, found it quite intereseting. However, I found it tightly coupled with ASP.Net MVC. I'de appreciate it if you demonstrate how to consume this service from both client and server side.